# timestamp to include milisec php

Tags: php, sql, microtime

i have a function that uses current timestamp to fetch some data and sql table, but some data get's doubled because the are in the same second and runs twice.

I need to fetch them with timestamp including miliseconds.

i use

```
$timestamp = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

is there anything like:

```
$serverTime = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s:milisecs');
```

I tried to inlcude milisecs with microtime() in $timestamp but had no luck until now.

Comment: http://php.net/microtime#112725

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = microtime();
echo $t;
```

This one works for me, i get the milliseconds and the current timestamp. Wheres your problem?

Comment: Well, indeed, thats a problem. I would probably find a solution, but you already posted a proper one above as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime->format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
?>
```

Comment: 2014-01-14 16:40:59.000000
 milisecs are always 0 for some reason :/

Comment: $date = date_create();
$timestamp = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'); like this? cause it does the same :/

Comment: As it seems to me, it produces the same, does it work for you?